# Client asking for estimate to set up/ configure his server

Tags: web-development, website-design, server, freelancer

I am building a web application for a client. I never set up a server using IIS. He needs me to configure the server to work with mySQL, php, and phpmyadmin. The server, is completely empty/unconfigured version of IIS 6. I need to set it up so the web application I built is completely accessible on the www. Not sure how long this will take me. It may take anywhere from 10-50 hours, I am not sure. I worked on set up servers using IIS, I never configured one from scratch. I am afraid that troubleshooting, and getting everything working as it should may take me days...

What would be a reasonable charge for this service?

I appreciate any advice,

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your location. Rates can be radically different depending on where you live. The best estimate is to **find someone who provides that service locally**.

Once you find him, I suggest you **refer your client** to him because setting a new server and making it secure requires experience which you admit not having.

You may subcontract the work for a fee if you are looking to add to your income but that depends on the relationship between you and you client. Some busy clients prefer this since it gives them a single point of contact for service and payment.

Should you really want to do it yourself, then charge something similar, probably a bit less, than the one you found locally. Expect to have to do some adjustments and monitoring for a few days right after the installation, to make sure you got everything right.

Comment: +1, toda raba Itai, I live in the U.S and have no clue what this would cost.